# Is WHERE clause applied before JOIN

Tags: oracle, join, where-clause, having

Is it fair to say that a `WHERE` clause will be applied on the row before any joins are applied, whereas a `HAVING` clause will be applied on the final result set after all joins and all aggregate functions have been applied?

Comment: From a logical point of view, all predicates (including join predicates) are done simultaneously - in practice, they are done in whatever order the optimiser decides to do them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it fair to say that a WHERE clause will be applied on the row data before any joins are applied

Nope, optimizer may change the order of joined tables. So the joined table may technically go before the table you've specified in `FROM`. So technically a condition from `WHERE` may become a part of a `JOIN` condition.

> HAVING clause will be applied on the final result set after all joins and all aggregate functions have been applied

That's right

Answer (score 0):

WHERE vs HAVING makes sense only for SQL statements including a GROUP BY clause. Filter predicates in the WHERE clause are applied first, then aggregation, and then filter predicates in the HAVING clause.

Example:

```
create table t(
   a varchar2(10) not null
  ,b varchar2(10) not null
  ,n number       not null
  ,primary key(a,b) 
);

insert into t values('A', '1', 10);
insert into t values('A', '2', 20);

insert into t values('B', '1', -10);
insert into t values('B', '2', 10);

insert into t values('C', '1', 0);
insert into t values('C', '2', 10);
insert into t values('C', '3', 20);
```

In the following query, {C,1} is removed before aggregation. See the count(*).

```
select a, sum(n), count(*)
  from t
 where n <> 0
 group by a;

A  SUM(N) COUNT(*)
== ====== =====
A  30     2
B  0      2
C  30     2
```

In this query, both {B,1} and {B,2} are removed since their sum is 0. But notice that {C,1} is included.

```
select a, sum(n), count(*)
  from t
 group by a
 having sum(n) <> 0; 

A  SUM(N) COUNT(*)
== ====== =====
A  30     2
C  30     3
```

One final note: 
Filter predicates in the WHERE clause are performed **before** join operations. At least "logically" . However, I can imagine some cases involving query rewrites against Materialized Views such as a pre-joined tables with indexes when this works a bit different "under the hood". Still, the result is the same.